# SilkTest: HTML tag associated to a DomElement object

Tags: silktest

I have a SilkTest DomElement object, and I need to get the HTML tag associated to this DomElement.
How can I do this?
Thanks.

```
// Silk4J
DomElement column = row.getCell(i);
if (???) {
  // TD case
} else {
  // TH case
}
```

I may need it for others HTML tags too.

Comment: Which language are you using? Silk4J, Silk4Net, or is it a Workbench .NET script? Can you show us a piece of your code highlighting the element whose tag you want to get?

Comment: Code included. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: There is a workaround with: r.getProperty("innerHtml"). If anyone has a better solution, let me know.